# Retime pop-up missing in Final Cut Pro 10.3.4

Tags: video-editing, final-cut-pro

I've been using FCPX(Final Cut Pro 10) for a long time and when I installed a different version of FCPX(10.3.4) in my MacBook Pro due to a HDD Failure. I started with a new project and wanted to reverse a clip. I went in search of the Retime Button which should look like [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12642?locale=en_US):

[image: Taken from Apple website]

but instead mine looks like this:

[image: My FCPX]

Please tell me where to find the reverse option. Thank you!

Comment: 10.4.4 is current, btw - run your App Store updater.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin I'll run the App Store updater as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong side of the editor window!
Look to the left of that line, at the **bottom-left corner of the viewer** where the preview is shown.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @grg! In FCP 10.0.9 It was in that place. Sorry about my Illiteracy!

Comment: @Karthik No problem at all you're absolutely right, it changed location in the 10.3 redesign. As usual, a downvoter is not a fan of such Q&As :/